# More, extra instead of "overcharged", "ripped me off"

Tags: word-usage

> The cabby charged me more.

> The cabby charged me extra.

Do these sentences work instead of:

> The cabby overcharged me/ripped me off.

Do they sound natural and are they likely to be used?

Can "higher" be used here too?

> The cabby charged me higher.

Comment: We really aren't supposed to act as editors.

Comment: charged me more [than x]. more is a comparative. express or implied.

Comment: @Lambie are you implying that "more" is likely to be used in this context, or were you just making a general statement?

Answer (score 1):

"More" and "higher" don't really work well, you need to make a clearer comparison.  Extra might be possible but you should say what the reason for the charge is.

It is fine to say "The cabbie charged me more {than he did last week/than he charged my friend/than was shown on the meter/...}"  These involve a direct comparison of one charge with another.

You can also say "The cabbie charged me extra for {taking the scenic route/for going south of the river/for working after midnight}.  These involve a charge for a specific service.

You could even say "The cabbie charged me extra for {not speaking English/being a tourist}"  These would be unjustified and often illegal charges.

But if you just want to say that the cabbie increased your charge, just to make more money from you then you would say "the cabbie overcharged me".

Comment: Does "higher" actually work with "charge" instead of "more"? (Not in this context)

Comment: This charge was high... that charge was higher.  Seems fine to me